# Using Apache Spark with a local S3-compatible Object store

Tags: apache-spark, object-storage

I am trying to run a simple Apache spark (Cloudera) read operation using a local object store that is fully s3 sdk/api compatible.  But I can not seem to figure out how to get Spark to understand that I am trying to access a *local* S3 bucket and not remote AWS/S3.

Here's what I've tried...

```
pyspark2 --conf spark.hadoop.hadoop.security.credential.provider.path=jceks://hdfs/user/myusername/awskeyfile.jceks --conf fs.s3a.endpoint=https://myenvironment.domain.com
df = spark.read.parquet("s3a://mybucket/path1/")
```

Error message...

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com:443 [mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/12.345.678.90] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

I can list the local bucket contents without issue on the command-line so I know that I have the access/secret key correct but I need to make Spark understand *not* to reach out to aws to try and resolve the bucket url.

Thanks.

#### Update / Resolution:

The fix to the issue was a missing prerequisite jar at maven coordinates: `org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.6.0`

So the final pyspark call looked like:

```
pyspark2 --conf spark.hadoop.hadoop.security.credential.provider.path=jceks://hdfs/user/myusername/awskeyfile.jceks --conf fs.s3a.endpoint=https://myenvironment.domain.com --jars hadoop-aws-2.6.0.jar
df = spark.read.parquet("s3a://mybucket/path1/")
```

Comment: You'll need to set the logging leve of logging.level.com.amazonaws to DEBUG to see what's happening. This error can mean lot of stuff...

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in HDP docs, [Working with third party object stores](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.0.0/bk_cloud-data-access/content/s3-third-party.html).

Settings are the same for CDH.

It comes down

- endpoint `fs.s3a.endpoint` = hostname
- disable DNS to bucket map `fs.s3a.path.style.access` = true
- play with signing options.

There are a few other switches you can turn for better compatibility; they're in those docs.

You might find the [Cloudstore `storediag`](https://github.com/steveloughran/cloudstore) command useful.